# Issue connecting to test database in django

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm running tests on Django (2.2.3) with Postgres.

According to [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database), when running tests, it should create a throw away database named by prefixing the normal database name with **test_**.

However this is not happening for me: the tests use the normal database! (intermittently - see edit)

Here are the relevant settings:

```
# Another module where I define these values
from conf.vars import DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_USER

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        # I added the following to see if it makes a difference, but no.
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_' + DB_NAME,
        },
    }
}
```

My manage.py file has the usual stuff including this line:

```
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

EDIT: Something very weird is going on!

The reason I detected this issue is because FactoryBoy was throwing FK conflicts when creating a user with generated email (on which I have a unique constraint), which should not be the case. That's what led me to realise the tests were connecting to the main database, not a throw away one.

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "User %03d" % n)
    email = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "email %03d" % n)
    password = make_password('welcome')
```

If I delete the users from the main database, and re-run the tests, in the print outs it tells me `Creating test database for alias 'default'...` (and a print out on the connection params shows it is creating a throw away database with **test_** prefix) - but the tests fail because `Key (user_id)=(61) is not present in table "user_user".` which is confusing as you'd have thought the Sequence from FactoryBoy resets...

If I run the tests again without any change to the code or the database, I do NOT get the print out telling me `Creating test database for alias 'default'...` and indeed it connects to the main database, and I get the `Key (email)=(email 000) already exists.` error.

If I go and delete the records again, it goes back the previous state of creating a test database but still failing.

If I delete the main database, I cannot run tests because it seems to want to connect to that in the first instance.

Am I maybe doing something silly with Postgres, or might it be caching connections or something?